# Using realloc to increase size vs creating bigger dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am asking this question for the sake of learning; normally I would use vector or linked list for this problem.

If the size of a dynamic array is changing throughout the main code, which is more efficient or logical to use: creating a new dynamic array which is half size bigger than the previous one and copying previous elements to it, or using realloc to make the dynamic array bigger? And if one of them is more efficient or logical, why?

Comment: `or using realloc` -- realloc will not work if the array is of non-POD types, such as `std::string`.

Comment: Do the objects need to be in contiguous memory for some reason? If not, why not just eliminate that constraint and it all becomes painless.

Comment: Memory takes time to allocate so if you know the maximum size of elements your array will have then by all means allocate or [reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) ahead of time. If you don't, then you really need to profile your application to understand the best approach. We can't really answer that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realloc` could extend the existing memory block in place if there's room, avoiding the whole allocate + copy + free process entirely. Using `new[]` doesn't allow for that possibility.

If you're writing idiomatic C++ you should use `std::vector`, which does the same thing under the hood. But for the sake of learning, if you don't have `std::vector` then use `realloc`.

Note that `realloc` is not object-aware. It won't call constructors and destructors. If you're going to use it in C++ you'd better know exactly what you're doing!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And what is trivial types?

Comment: what is?  search for  "c++ trivial types"